# Error trying to run Samba in Ubuntu MATE 19.04

Tags: networking, server, dpkg, samba, services

When checking the status:

```
smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: inactive (dead)
    Docs: man:smbd(8)
          man:samba(7)
          man:smb.conf(5)

abr 30 19:20:02 (nome_do_pc) systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/smbd.service:9: 
PIDFile= references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/samba/smbd.pid → /run/samba/smbd.pid; pl

abr 30 19:20:04 (nome_do_pc) systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/smbd.service:9: 
PIDFile= references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/samba/smbd.pid → /run/samba/smbd.pid; pl

abr 30 19:20:05 (nome_do_pc) systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/smbd.service:9: 
PIDFile= references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/samba/smbd.pid → /run/samba/smbd.pid; pl

...skipping...
```

Trying to restart:

```
Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Trying to reinstall:

```
Samba is not being run as an AD Domain Controller: Masking samba-ad-dc.service
Please ignore the following error about deb-systemd-helper not finding those services.
(samba-ad-dc.service already masked)
Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "restart" failed.
smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-04-30 19:37:40 -03; 6ms ago
  Docs: man:smbd(8)
        man:samba(7)
        man:smb.conf(5)
 Process: 20244 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group $SMBDOPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 20244 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
abr 30 19:37:40 (nome_do_pc) systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
abr 30 19:37:40 (nome_do_pc) smbd[20244]: [2019/04/30 19:37:40.547061,  0] ../../lib/param/loadparm.c:1609(set_variable_helper)
abr 30 19:37:40 (nome_do_pc) smbd[20244]: set_variable_helper(Yes): value is not boolean!
abr 30 19:37:40 (nome_do_pc) systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
abr 30 19:37:40 (nome_do_pc) systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
abr 30 19:37:40 (nome_do_pc) systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote samba (--configure):
 o subprocesso instalado, do pacote samba, o post-installation  script returned an error of exit status 1
Processing 'triggers' for ufw (0.36-1ubuntu1) ...
Regras atualizadas para o perfil 'Samba'
Reloaded firewall 
Processing 'triggers' for systemd (240-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing 'triggers' for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing 'triggers' for libc-bin (2.29-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered during processing of:
 samba
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will get that exact error message if security is set to share in smb.conf.

Run the following command:

```
testparm -s
```

Do you get an error:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid value 'share' for parameter 'security'
Error loading services.
```

If you do then edit /etc/samba/smb.conf and find the `security = share` line and delete it.

Then restart smbd again.